# .NET 6 Custom Nuget package referencing other packages - Do I have to include the other packages myself?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nuget, nuget-package-restore

In my project I am using a NuGet package that was written by the team that I'm a part of. Say it's called `MyNugetPackage`.

`MyNugetPackage` references another NuGet packages, such as `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis` package. This package is not included in my project. Just in MyNugetPackage.

The thing is - when I upload my code to the global CI/CD pipe we are working with - I'm getting an exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[removed]'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I hate to say this, but everything works in my computer. It just fails the CI/CD process with this error.

My question is: how to solve this error? I had a speculation that maybe `MyNugetPackage` is not updated in the cloud and therefore can't find the path for `StackExchangeRedis` package.

Another option that I was thinking about is to include the missing NuGet packages in my project, but I have no idea if that's a good approach. I mean, we made `MyNugetPackage`, so why should my project include everything that nuget includes?

Thanks in advance.

Every change that I'm doing has to be followed with proper explanation. I can't just push my updates to the cloud without being sure that's the solution. So I only have speculations and not proper examples of what I tried.

Comment: We might need to know what the CI/CD process is. It's' possible your CI/CD is not contacting NuGet to resolve dependencies. As long as your NuGet package has the correct dependencies listed, it should build properly.

Comment: If package that your team created and it has deoendency on another package you don't have to install that package - unless your are using older version of .net that uses package.config. Also your CI/CD should have Nuget restore command to restore all dependencies before build.